# Sending sensitive data from react to node js express server

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, cryptography, jwt

I watched many tutorial and even checked some blog guides on JWT authentication with react, and express, however, I found that people seem to be sending sensitive information like password as JSON object to express using the POST method. I am concerned whether this is the right way, can't hacker see these information if they are not encrypted? and if so how can I implement such an encryption so that I can encrypt the payload before sending it to express.

Comment: You can generate tokens by using otplib on the client-side and decode this on the server-side. if it's verified then proceed further

Comment: Here is the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/otplib

Comment: Does it encrypt the payload?

Comment: Use HTTPS, like everybody else.

Comment: Is it enough to use https?

Comment: No require to encrypt but to use a secret key to generate OTP are same on both sides so it will verify, OTP will valid for a certain times like 30sec

Comment: If i use it will it hide the payload?

Comment: If anyone try to hack it wont because of secret key used on both side

Comment: Alright thanks, i think i will use both solutions together to improve the security of my website

Comment: So you have to understand the concepts behind this. Basically, the client app is considered untrusted. That is, all code returned to and executed in the browser can be compromised. So a user can install a malicious browser extension and that can inject itself into ANY encryption you might add. 

That means if user enters their password on a compromised system, they're screwed and there is nothing you can do about it (short of handing out locked down computers). (continued in next comment)

Comment: There is, however, a different attack surface, where the system of your user is not compromised, but the network is. In most scenarios, just using HTTPS is enough as the OS of any computer (and mobile device/IoT) handles this for you -> unless the user is tricked into trusting a third party CA or you lose the keys to your certificate or one of publicly trusted CAs is compromised, you're good. This is why for 'most apps' it is enough to use HTTPs to POST pre-shared credentials (aka passwords) over it (continued in next comment)

Comment: What you could do, however, is add an extra layer to this where you will not send the passwords but a one-time-only (to prevent replay attack) encrypted payload. You can do this in any/many ways e.g. use TOTP to give you an AES key and then send your username/password AES encrypted and return tokens back encrypted with the next TOTP.
You can put those additional factors into hardware as tokens that users need to insert into their device to login to your system.

However, this will ONLY mitigate the MiTM attack (someone listening in via network)

Comment: And while it does so, you need to weigh up security vs usability. If you're building a run-of-the-mill app, how important is it for your users if their data leaks vs how prepared they are to deal with MFA / hardware tokens to use it?

And for most apps the answer to this is 'screw this, we're just doing HTTPS'. Which is why most apps code just needs to ensure that connection is not over HTTP and then POST the passwords directly to the backend.

Comment: Omg this is a great answer, thank you for the great and detailed explanation, could you please post these as the answer so that i can mark it as answered?